# How to addFields for later defining relation with Sangria for graphQL?

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

While deriving an object type i want to add an field with the AddFields-methode of Sangria. I don't know how to fill the parameter "resolve = "
Can anyone help me?

Given are the entities Delivery and System. I derived the object Type SystemD4S.
Now I want to add a field "systemObject" with type SystemD4S in the derived object type for delivery. Don't know how to fill the parameter "resolve = "

```
case class Delivery (
                     docid: String,
                     override val docType: String = Doctype.DELIVERY,
                     system: String,
                     status: String,
                     items: List[DeliveryItem],
                     deleted: Boolean
                     ) extends EntityItemCollection {
  def getBusinessKey: String = s"$docid::$docType::$system"
}

case class System(id: String, company: String)

val SystemD4S = deriveObjectType[D4sEntityRepo, System](
    ObjectTypeDescription("system"))

val DeliveryD4S = deriveObjectType[D4sEntityRepo, Delivery](
    ObjectTypeDescription("delivery"),
    AddFields(Field("systemObject", SystemD4S, resolve = c => enitiesD4S.deferRel()))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

resolve is a function of type `Context[Ctx, Val] ⇒ Action[Ctx, Res]`.

For `deriveObjectType[D4sEntityRepo, Delivery]`, your `Ctx` is `D4sEntityRepo`, `Val` is `Delivery` and `Res` is `SystemD4S`

Now to get the `enitiesD4S` instance in your resolve function, you can use `c.ctx`.

```
val DeliveryD4S = deriveObjectType[D4sEntityRepo, Delivery](
    ObjectTypeDescription("delivery"),
    AddFields(Field("systemObject", SystemD4S, resolve = c => c.ctx.deferRel()))
  )
```

Hope this helps.